# Display image in imageview by SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-imageview, simpleadapter

I am new android now I want to display image from an url. I am using imageview in listview. I want to add the list of images into the each row of the list item. I used SimpleAdapter but the imageview shows blank.

Here's the main activity:

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    public class ReadComments extends ListActivity {

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // testing on Emulator:
        private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://192.168.30.198/test/webservice/comments.php";


        // JSON IDS:
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
        private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "post_id";
        private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
        private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";


        // An array of all of our comments
        private JSONArray mComments = null;
        // manages all of our comments in a list.
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            // loading the comments via AsyncTask
            new LoadComments().execute();
        }

        public void addComment(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, AddComment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
         */
        public void updateJSONdata() {
            mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();      
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

            try {
                mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                    // gets the content of each tag
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
                    map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    mCommentList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
         */
        private void updateList() { 
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                            TAG_USERNAME,TAG_IMAGE }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                            R.id.username, R.id.imageView1 });

            // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
            setListAdapter(adapter);    

            ListView lv = getListView();    
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {}
            });
        }

        public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadComments.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                updateList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you saved in your  `map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);`?

Comment: Not possible with the `SimpleAdapter` alone. You need to create a custom adapter extending `SimpleAdapter` or any other adapter(BaseAdapter ,ArrayAdapter etc) to achieve that..

Comment: do you have example create custom SimpleAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

**add** this code just after the `setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);` on your **MainActivity**

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

and the IDE will automatically ask you to import  **android.os.StrictMode** library.

and think about using a base adapter